# why is this code giving me EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I get the bad access when followLink is called. This does not happen if I paste the openURL line into textContainsURL, so I'm assuming the object no longer exists once the method finishes? I'm new to this but I though ARC was supposed to handle this sort of thing for you?

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
{   
NSURL *newsURL;
}

@end
```

following is in the implementation:

```
- (void)followLink
{ 
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:newsURL];

}

- (BOOL)textContainsURL:(NSString*)text
{
    NSError *error = NULL;
    //scan text to see if there is a link and only set this up if there is
    NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink error:&error];

    NSArray *matches = [detector matchesInString:text
                                     options:0
                                       range:NSMakeRange(0, [text length])];

    for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) 
    {
        //NSRange matchRange = [match range];
        if ([match resultType] == NSTextCheckingTypeLink) 
        {
            newsURL = [[NSURL alloc] init];
            newsURL = [match URL];//what's the void state? retain it
            return YES;
        }
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: What's the point of `newsURL = [[NSURL alloc] init];`? Where do you define newsURL?

Comment: You don't need to alloc-init `newsURL` as you assign it again afterwards. This is just a side note, not the fix (assuming ARC isn't buggy).

Comment: ok, I actually only just added that in in an uninformed attempt to fix things. I'll edit the question. and newsURL is in the header. I'll put that in too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should copy the matched URL to your newsURL ivar or make your newsURL ivar a copy property and set the value through the accessor method. In your current code the URL is autoreleased.